# I'm trying to develop tkinter app using oops but getting this error

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have just started to practice Oops concepts.I'm watching simple Oops video and trying too use apply steps to the tkinter problrm. I don't why I'm getting this error.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font as tkFont

top = Tk()
top.minsize(width=1280,height=720)
top.maxsize(width=721,height=521)
class Framesone:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, frame1, text1, x2, y2):
        self.stframe = LabelFrame(top, width=300, height=200, highlightcolor="grey", bd=5)
        self.stframe.place(x=x1, y=y1)
        self.label1 = Label(frame1, text=text1)
        self.label1.config(font=("Times", "25", "bold", "italic"))
        self.label1.place(x=x2, y=y2)
Framesone(100,200,Framesone().stframe,"HI",20,30)
top.mainloop()
```

OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python projects my/Basic Programs/MQC FIt Software.py", line 14, in <module>
    Framesone(100,200,Framesone().stframe,"HI",20,30)
TypeError: __init__() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'x1', 'y1', 'frame1', 'text1', 'x2', and 'y2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: When you use: `Framesone().stframe`, you first call `Framesone()` with no arguments but it expects 6 arguments.

Comment: Also I wonder why you're generating a `Framesone` object without retaining it. It seems like you're using object initialization as if it's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Framesone(100,200,Framesone().stframe,"HI",20,30)
```

`Framesone().stframe` calls the `__init__` function without arguments.
Everytime you call `MyClass()` the `__init__` function for that class gets called.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `Framesone().stframe` the code first calls the `__init__()` function of `Framesone()`, but without any arguments. You're using the object's instance variables before you have declared the object itself.

As you've defined the `stframe` already in your object you could simply replace references to `frame1` with `self.stframe` as in your example these are the same.

```py
class Framesone:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, text1, x2, y2):
        self.stframe = LabelFrame(top, width=300, height=200, highlightcolor="grey", bd=5)
        self.stframe.place(x=x1, y=y1)
        self.label1 = Label(self.stframe, text=text1)
        self.label1.config(font=("Times", "25", "bold", "italic"))
        self.label1.place(x=x2, y=y2)

Framesone(100, 200, "HI", 20, 30)
```

If you do want to use this `stframe` the way you're using it now, you could move the `stframe` declaration outside of the `__init__()` function. This would change `stframe` from being an instance variable to being a static variable. This would allow you to call `Framesone.stframe` from outside your class without calling its constructor. (Note you're now calling `Framesone` without the `()` indicating you're using its static class variable instead of an instance variable.)

```py
class Framesone:
    stframe = LabelFrame(top, width=300, height=200, highlightcolor="grey", bd=5)
    
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, frame1, text1, x2, y2):
        self.stframe.place(x=x1, y=y1)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text=text1)
        self.label1.config(font=("Times", "25", "bold", "italic"))
        self.label1.place(x=x2, y=y2)

Framesone(100, 200, Framesone.stframe, "HI", 20, 30)
```

Edit: removed `self` from class static variable. Changed wording slightly for better explanation of instance vs static variable